# How to detect if the user has clicked 'cancel' in the wallet when WalletConnect v2 SignClient invokes 'eth_sendTransaction'?

Tags: angular, wallet-connect

I need to integrate WalletConnect v2 in Angular, and I've chosen to use SignClient to handle related operations. When I call the 'eth_sendTransaction' method, a transaction confirmation dialog appears in the wallet. If the user clicks 'cancel' in the wallet's confirmation dialog, my Angular application cannot detect that the user has performed a cancel operation. How can I handle this to receive a notification about the cancellation? Thank you very much.

```
async sendTransaction() {
    try {
      const result = await this.signClient.request({
        topic: session.topic,
        chainId: 'eip155:5',
        request: {
          method: "eth_sendTransaction",
          params: [
            {
              from: "0x...",
              to: "0x...",
              data: "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675",
              gas: "0x76c0", // 30400
              gasPrice: "0x9184e72a000", // 10000000000000
              value: "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
              nonce: "0x117", // 279·
            },
          ],
        }
      });
      console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

I have referred to the web3modal example provided on the WalletConnect v2 official website and used the 'sendTransaction' method provided by 'wagmi,' but I still face the same issue. I have tested the WalletConnect v2 integration example in React, and I did not encounter this problem.

My expectation is that when integrating with Angular and making an 'eth_sendTransaction' call, I can receive notification messages for user cancellation events.